# Custom border with smooth edges using CSS and Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, border

How I do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbTup.png) with CSS and Bootstrap?

The closest I got was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpvOC.png).

I'm using version 4 of Bootstrap.

Code:

```
<div class="row text-center" style="height: 6.875vh;">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <a class="mw-100" id="like" href="#">
                <img class="rounded-circle border-2 border-purple" src="img/like.png" alt="Like" title="Like">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center bg-white" style="height: 11.71875vh;">
        <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
            <a id="prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <img class="mw-100" src="img/prev.png" alt="Anterior" title="Anterior">
                <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4 my-auto text-left">
            <a id="next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <img class="mw-100" src="img/next.png" alt="Próximo" title="Próximo">
                <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Rafael! Welcome to stack overflow. Just taking a high-level stab at the question, but I believe that Bootstrap has a "Thickness" parameter, which would mean you just need to adjust the thickness in the framework. If not, you can do it manually through CSS. However, without access to your image files I cannot test this in a Fiddle. It could be helpful to add this to a JSfiddle URL and link the working example here, since it would allow others the ability to more easily collaborate on the problem.

Comment: At JSfiddle, the page appears different, whit same code

https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelvida/h67m1axs/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your very close and the correct approach seems to be

- having a circle border (like you have)
- having the circle on top of a colored bar
- the edges that you miss can be filled by having to triangles on each side of the image

I always wanted to do this... thank you for asking this :)

working snippet below:

```css
#backgroundPanel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

#imageContainer {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  background-image: url('https://www.akberiqbal.com/favicon.ico');
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -20px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#leftTriangle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: calc(50% - 45px);
  top: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid green;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid green;
}

#rightTriangle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: calc(50% - 45px);
  top: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid green;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="leftTriangle"></div>
<div id="rightTriangle"></div>
<div id='backgroundPanel'></div>
<div id='imageContainer'> <img src="" /> </div>
```

Comment: It works, thank you. I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB3Z1.png

Answer (score 0):

The Akber answer above solved my problem

I got this:

[image]

Code:

```css
#like {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 86px;
    height: 86px;
    left: calc(50% - 43px);
    border-width: 10.75px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#A11D5F;
    transform: translateY(8px);
}

#left-triangle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: calc(50% - 74px);
    top: calc(100% - 6px);
    background: transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 21.5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 21.5px solid #A11D5F;
    border-bottom: 21.5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 21.5px solid #A11D5F;
}

#right-triangle {       
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    right: calc(50% - 74px);
    top: calc(100% - 6px);
    background: transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 21.5px solid #A11D5F;
    border-right: 21.5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 21.5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 21.5px solid #A11D5F;
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center remove" style="height: 43px;">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4" id="like-content">
        <div id="left-triangle"></div>
        <div id="right-triangle"></div>
        <a href="#">
            <img id="like" src="img/like.png" alt="Like" title="Like">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>

<div class="row text-center bg-white remove" style="height: 11.71875vh;">
    <div class="col-4 my-auto text-right">
        <a id="prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="">
            <img class="mw-100" src="img/prev.png" alt="Anterior" title="Anterior">
            <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 my-auto text-left">
        <a id="next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <img class="mw-100" src="img/next.png" alt="Próximo" title="Próximo">
            <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```